# I am applying transform: scale(2) to make website compatible to visually impaired people. When I do a transfrom: scale(2), the

Tags: css

[image][image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fseH.png): https://When I do a transfrom: scale(2), the the fontsize increases, but the text is getting trimmed.i.stack.imgur.com/ppHr2.png

Answer (score 0):

Don't do scale() but use zoom css property. Read more about it here:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Edit: as i just read this is not web standard, so you should be careful about using this, it could happen that this won't work well with all browsers. But if it is working for your usecase go for it.

Comment: Hi Stefan. Thanks for the reply. But zoom isn't seem to be working in case of IE and Firefox, I mean the text size is not even increasing. Although zoom works perfectly fine in chrome. In case of transform, the text size is increasing, but IE and Firefox is treating it as an image and text is getting cropped. Please see the pic for reference. Please suggest. Thanks!